# How to open LUKS encrypted image file on cygwin / windows

Tags: encryption, cygwin, luks

Is it possible to open (decrypt) file encrypted with LUKS on cygwin / windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia page for [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) suggests [FreeOTFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTFE), a Windows program that can read LUKS files. However, the download page seems to be unavailable.

Comment: FreeOTFE page seems to be down, but it is possible to download binaries from [sourceforge mirror](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeotfe.mirror/).

Comment: Anyway it is freeware but not open source so I would not recommend to use it.

Comment: @Chemik it is open source, it even has a public domain licence: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeotfe.mirror/files/ 
Source is the last file